# Rubymine file reference

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I'm trying to reference a file to write to it using RubyMine and I'm having trouble figuring it out. When using the full path, the code errors out while running it with RubyMine.
When I use the same code and run it in terminal, the code works fine using the command:

ruby studio_game players.csv

How can I get the file to be recognized without having to designate the full path in RubyMine?

Erring Code:

```
require_relative 'player'
require_relative 'game'

player1 = Player.new("moe")
player2 = Player.new("larry", 60)
player3 = Player.new("curly", 125)

knuckleheads = Game.new("Knuckleheads")
knuckleheads.load_players(ARGV.shift || 'players.csv')
```

Error message:

```
/Users/MNickey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) "/Users/MNickey/RubymineProjects/PragmaticStudio/Stooges Game/studio_game"
/Users/MNickey/RubymineProjects/PragmaticStudio/Stooges Game/game.rb:83:in `readlines': No such file or directory - players.csv (Errno::ENOENT)
from /Users/MNickey/RubymineProjects/PragmaticStudio/Stooges Game/game.rb:83:in `load_players'
from /Users/MNickey/RubymineProjects/PragmaticStudio/Stooges Game/studio_game:9:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

`knuckleheads.load_players(ARGV.shift || 'players.csv')` is almost certainly what is causing the problem.  Unless you have configured the launcher for the script with a command line argument, ARGV will be empty and you will be getting plain-old 'players.csv' as the result.

I'm pretty certain you are running the script with an argument when you run it in the command line.

To set a command line parameter in RubyMine, go to Run / Edit Configurations, find the launch configuration for your script, and add the path to your csv file to the Script Arguments input box.